# Postman is returning a 404 error on my Spring Boot API

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I've built a spring boot rest api.  However, when I try to test it in Postman, I am getting a 404 error.  I have linked the code below.  Please note that there might be a random @component annotation in some files.  This was my tired brain trying anything it can.

Student.java

```
package StudentModel;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    public enum status {
        PAID,
        UNPAID,
        PARTIAL
    }
    
    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long Id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String FirstName;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String LastName;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long Phone;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String Email;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private status PaymentStatus;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public status getPaymentStatus() {
        return PaymentStatus;
    }

    public void setPaymentStatus(status paymentStatus) {
        PaymentStatus = paymentStatus;
    }   
}
```

StudentController.java

```
package StudentController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import StudentModel.Student;
import StudentService.StudentService;
@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    
    @PostMapping("/api/v1/addStudent")
    public Student addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return studentService.saveStudent(student);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/api/v1/addStudents")
    public List<Student> addStudents(@RequestBody List<Student> students) {
        return studentService.saveStudents(students);
        }
    @GetMapping("/api/v1/students")
    public List<Student> findAllStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }
    @GetMapping("/api/v1/students/{id}")
    public Student findStudentById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return studentService.getStudentById(id);
    }
    @GetMapping("/api/v1/students/{name}")
    public Student findStudentByFirstName(@PathVariable String FirstName) {
        return studentService.getStudentByFirstName(FirstName);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/api/v1/update")
    public Student updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return studentService.updateStudent(student);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/api/v1/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable long id) {
        return studentService.deleteStudent(id);
    }   
}
```

StudentService.java

```
package StudentService;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import StudentModel.Student;
import StudentRepository.StudentRepository;
@Component
@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentService {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }
    
    public List<Student> saveStudents(List<Student> students) {
        return studentRepository.saveAll(students);
    }
    
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Student getStudentById(long id){
        return studentRepository.getById(id);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByFirstName(String FirstName){
        return studentRepository.findByFirstName(FirstName);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByLastName(String LastName){
        return studentRepository.findByLastName(LastName);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByEmail(String Email){
        return studentRepository.findByEmail(Email);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByPhone(long Phone){
        return studentRepository.findByPhone(Phone);
    }
    
    public String deleteStudent(long id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "Student Deleted";
    }
    
    public Student updateStudent (Student student) {
        Student existingStudent = studentRepository.getById(student.getId());
        existingStudent.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
        existingStudent.setLastName(student.getLastName());
        existingStudent.setEmail(student.getEmail());
        existingStudent.setPhone(student.getPhone());
        existingStudent.setPaymentStatus(student.getPaymentStatus());
        return studentRepository.save(existingStudent);
    }
}
```

StudentRepository.java

```
package StudentRepository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import StudentModel.Student;
@Component
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository <Student, Long>{
//  Student saveStudent (Student student);
    Student findByFirstName(String FirstName);
    Student findByLastName(String LastName);
    Student findByEmail(String Email);
    Student findByPhone(long Phone);

//  Student findById(long id);
}
```

StudentApplication.java

```
package com.BusyQA;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan

public class BusyQaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusyQaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You could remove `@Component` when you already have `@RestController`. I think your resource have duplicated context, try remove `/api/v1/` from methods and keep only in class controller. Currently your resource is something like `/api/v1/api/v1/...`

Comment: Can you post the response and the stacktrace?

Comment: @Dimitris this is the response I get from postman:
```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-04-07T12:35:29.369+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/v1/addStudent"
}
```
The server doesn't throw any errors, so I'm not sure which stacktrace to look for.

Comment: @DilermandoLima I tried that but I'm still getting a 404 error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

To make it work, you need some improvements:

> 1. For `Controller` (`REST API` requests):
>
> - remove `@Component` annotation;
> - remove `/api/v1/` from request mappings;
> - add `DTO` to only transfer the required information;
> - fix the name of the variables, following the convention.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.demo.dto.StudentDTO;
import com.example.demo.entity.Student;
import com.example.demo.service.StudentService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/addStudent") 
    public Student addStudent(@RequestBody StudentDTO studentDTO) {
        Student student = new Student(studentDTO);
        return studentService.saveStudent(student);
    }

    @PostMapping("/addStudents") 
    public List<Student> addStudents(@RequestBody List<Student> students) {
        return studentService.saveStudents(students);
    }

    @GetMapping("/students") 
    public List<StudentDTO> findAllStudents() {
        List<StudentDTO> studentDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getStudents();

        for (Student student : studentList) {
            StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO(student);
            studentDTOList.add(studentDTO);
        }
        return studentDTOList;
    }

    @GetMapping("/students/id/{id}") 
    public Student findStudentById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return studentService.getStudentById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/students/firstName/{firstName}") 
    public Student findStudentByFirstName(@PathVariable String firstName) {
        return studentService.getStudentByFirstName(firstName);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update") 
    public Student updateStudent(@RequestBody StudentDTO studentDTO) {
        Student student = new Student(studentDTO);
        return studentService.updateStudent(student);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}") 
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable long id) {
        return studentService.deleteStudent(id);
    }
}
```

> 2. For `Service` class (Business logic):
>
> - remove `@Component` annotation;
> - remove `@Transactional` annotation;
> - use `findById()` to retrieve an entity by its `Id`;

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import com.example.demo.entity.Student;
import com.example.demo.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public List<Student> saveStudents(List<Student> students) {
        return studentRepository.saveAll(students);
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Student getStudentById(long id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

    public Student getStudentByFirstName(String firstName) {
        return studentRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public Student getStudentByLastName(String lastName) {
        return studentRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
    }

    public Student getStudentByEmail(String email) {
        return studentRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public Student getStudentByPhone(long phone) {
        return studentRepository.findByPhone(phone);
    }

    public String deleteStudent(long id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "Student Deleted";
    }

    public Student updateStudent(Student student) {
        Student existingStudent = studentRepository.getById(student.getId());
        existingStudent.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
        existingStudent.setLastName(student.getLastName());
        existingStudent.setEmail(student.getEmail());
        existingStudent.setPhone(student.getPhone());
        existingStudent.setPaymentStatus(student.getPaymentStatus());
        return studentRepository.save(existingStudent);
    }
}
```

> 3. The `Model` class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import com.example.demo.dto.StudentDTO;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Student {

    public Student(StudentDTO studentDTO) {
        this.id = studentDTO.getId();
        this.firstName = studentDTO.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = studentDTO.getLastName();
        this.phone = studentDTO.getPhone();
        this.email = studentDTO.getEmail();
        this.paymentStatus = studentDTO.getPaymentStatus();
    }

    public enum Status {
        PAID,
        UNPAID,
        PARTIAL
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private long phone;

    private String email;

    private Status paymentStatus;
}
```

> 4. `DTO` class:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Student;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.io.Serializable;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL;

@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class StudentDTO implements Serializable {

    public StudentDTO(Student student) {
        this.id = student.getId();
        this.firstName = student.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = student.getLastName();
        this.phone = student.getPhone();
        this.email = student.getEmail();
        this.paymentStatus = student.getPaymentStatus();
    }

    private long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private long phone;

    private String email;

    private Student.Status paymentStatus;
}
```

> 5. The `Repository` class:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    Student findByFirstName(String firstName);
    Student findByLastName(String lastName);
    Student findByEmail(String email);
    Student findByPhone(long phone);
}
```

and the main class of a `Spring Boot` application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

To test it, you can use endpoints by the same principle:

> **POST:** localhost:8080/api/v1/addStudent
> **POST:** localhost:8080/api/v1/addStudents
> **GET:** localhost:8080/api/v1/students
> **GET:** localhost:8080/api/v1/students/id/1
> **GET:** localhost:8080/api/v1/students/firstName/testName
> **PUT:** localhost:8080/api/v1/update
> **DELETE:** localhost:8080/api/v1/delete/1

Answer (score 1):

As Dilermando mentioned in the comments, your `@RequestMapping("/api/v1")` is setting its mapping, then you're extending onto that with `@PostMapping("/api/v1/addStudent")` making the address `{url}/api/v1/api/v1/addStudent`. You can resolve this by removing the /api/v1 from the Post/get mappings:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    
    @PostMapping("/addStudent")
    public Student addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return studentService.saveStudent(student);
    }

...etc
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm having the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: @Castor Are you use `Spring Security` in your program?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I currently have spring security disabled in the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

> There are 2 reason behind 404 not found

#### Problem 1

You main class is in `com.BusyQA` package and Controller class is in `StudentController` package so you have to scan controller class in main class.

Your `StudentApplication.java` class should become:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = StudentController.class) // Scan the controller class in main class.

public class BusyQaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusyQaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

#### Problem 2

Remove pre path `/api/v1` from all url mapping in controller. Now your mapping url should become

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class StudentController {
  
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
  
    @PostMapping("/addStudent")
  
    @PostMapping("/addStudents")
  
    @GetMapping("/students")
 
    @GetMapping("/students/{id}")

    @GetMapping("/students/{name}")
  
    @PutMapping("/update")
  
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
  
}
```

This is another mistake in your code:

- Remove the `@Component` annotation from controller.
- Remove the `@Component` annotation from Service class.
- Remove the `@Component` annotation from Repository interface and add `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've gone ahead and implemented those changes.  However, I am still getting the error from postman.

Comment: Thank you!  I have implemented your suggested updates, however the problem persists.  My console now throws the following warning: "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]"

Comment: I have already removed spring security dependency.  The problem still persists.

Comment: it fires on: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/addStudent"

Comment: Yes I am. I'm at a loss at the moment.  I will try to start the project all over again and see if it works.