# Spring Boot Returns 404-Not found error Intermittently

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kubernetes

I have a set of endpoints, which runs locally without any issues. I am able to access the endpoints and it returns valid responses.

When I run the same application in kubernetes pod, it returns successful response but also randomly returns below error,

{
"timestamp": 1690829218011,
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"path": "/api/v1/addStudents"
}

There are no load balancer or multiple instances of the application is running. The application is running only in 1 pod.

Request to provide some pointers on how to troubleshoot this issue. As there are no error message written in application logs. And this happens intermittently.

Spring Boot Version: 2.7.6
Java Version: Java 11

Followed suggestions in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318107/spring-boot-cannot-access-rest-controller-on-localhost-404](https://stackoverflow.com) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71780984/postman-is-returning-a-404-error-on-my-spring-boot-api](https://stackoverflow.com)

Inputs on how to troubleshoot this intermittent issue.